# Delete selected row from datagrid view and update mysql database in C#

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

m developing application for my office and in my application there is a datagrid view that linked to a mysql database. local users can update the database using datagridview but they cant delete any recodes. i want to implement a method that user's are select exact raw in the datagridview and delete it  as well as delete the database record soon. i managed to make select and delete datagridview row using below code but it not update the database

```
private void button60_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
            {
                if (oneCell.Selected)
                    dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
            }

        }
```

and this is my connection string that i normally use to view the database data in datagrid view. i don't have good knowledge to combined these two.can someone please show me how to do that

my connection string

private void showdatagrid()
        {

```
        string constring = string.Format("datasource='{0}';username=******;port=3306;password=***********;Connect Timeout=20000;Command Timeout=28800", dbserverip.Text);
        MySqlConnection conwaqDatabase = new MySqlConnection(constring);
        MySqlCommand cmdwaqDatabase = new MySqlCommand(" select * from warit.loans ; ", conwaqDatabase);


        try
        {

            MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter();
            sda.SelectCommand = cmdwaqDatabase;
            dbdataset = new DataTable();
            sda.Fill(dbdataset);
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();

            bsource.DataSource = dbdataset;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(dbdataset);

        }


        catch (Exception ex)
        {


            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);

        }
```

Comment: where you're removing row from data gridview also use 'delete from table_name where column_name=value'

Comment: thank you for the answer can you please edit this code for me because i already tried more than 10 times but i cant figure it out. i'm new to programming :(

Comment: do you have a primary key in your database table?

Comment: No i assigned a primary key  as a auto-increment value, i want to delete exact datadridvew row what user selected

Comment: what is the criteria to delete the row? which column value you will use to delete the row? e.g FirstName, SSN etc

Comment: No i want to delete user selected raw. i mainly filter my datagrid with "loannumber" value. but there my be duplicate values. deleting row  using "loannumber" value may be delete two rows.that's why i want to delete selected row

Comment: can you please tell me name of one or more columns because by using only 'loannumber' query will delete all records of 'loannumber'. if you can attach a screenshot it will be very helpful :)

Comment: these are the all columns "loannumber" "loantype" "neworsecond" "purpose" "status" "checkedby" "date" "username"  "lid" "comments" lid is a primary key

Comment: i tried to attach screenshot but i cant because of very low reputation :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this code

```
private void button60_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (DataGridViewCell oneCell in dataGridView1.SelectedCells)
    {
        if (oneCell.Selected)
        {
            dataGridView1.Rows.RemoveAt(oneCell.RowIndex);
            int loannumber = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells['index of loannumber column in datagridview'].Value; // assuming loannmber is integer
            string username = dataGridView1.Rows[oneCell.RowIndex].Cells['index of username column in datagridview'].Value; // assuming username is string
            /* Now create an object of MySqlConnection and MySqlCommand
             * and the execute following query
             */
            string query = string.Format("DELETE FROM table_name WHERE loannumber = {0} AND username = '{1}'", loannumber, username);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks sir but what are the values should i replace with index values ? i put 0 and 7 but it's not working

Comment: do you replace the 'table_name' and what is the data types of 'loannumber' and 'username'?

Comment: yes data values are correct int and string and i replaced the table_name names :(

Comment: i tried to post my whole code here but it's too long sir what can i do ?

Comment: can you use teamviewer?

Comment: you are an amazing programmer sir. thank you for everything. your are a very good man. really really good man your knowledge is outstanding. i'll vote you as soon as i get enough reputation sir.

Comment: it was my duty @SemiraUthsala :) happy coding

Comment: dear sir i want one more help from you.i successfully created my application and all the functions are working properly now (Thanks to you ) but i want to save my application configuration based on user by using app.config. i saved my connection string in settings inside app.config and call my connection string using  properties.settings.default.mydabconnection; but nothing happens. applications says it cant connect with database. why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

```cs
string connection = "server = URL; uid = user; pwd = password; database = database;";

using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connection)) {

    conn.Open();

    string idLocRemv = dataGridView1.SelectedRows[0].Cells[0].Value.ToString();

    string removeVolCred = "DELETE FROM TableName WHERE ID = " + idLocRemv;

    using (MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(removeVolCred, fbcConn)) {
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

*Apply necessary exception handlers. (try catch finally)*

**Additionally, you will need to re-load DataGridView afterwards.**